# XAML: Is there some ways that I could declare a variable for Margin property?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, margin

I want to declare a variable for Margin value like this:

```
<x:MarginStruct x:Key="myMargin1">10,5,20,20</x:MarginStruct>
```

then I could reuse this resource value for some UI elements like this:

```
<TextBlock Margin={StaticResource myMargin1}">text1</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Margin={StaticResource myMargin1}">text2</TextBlock>
```

Should I define a class/struct MarginStruct with four double members?

If that is a way, what if margin value likes "10,5" or "10" in some situations, how should we handle it?

Thanks! Any ideas is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare this resource:

`<Thickness x:Key="MyMargin" Left="10" Top="5" Right="20" Bottom="20" />`
and then use this:

```
<TextBlock Margin={StaticResource MyMargin}">text1</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried <x:Thickness x:Key="myMargin">10,5,20,20</x:Thickness> before and failed, what's the meaning of char "x"?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio can create this variable for you.

In the text block properties window click little square next to the padding boxes and then click "convert to new resource".

[click link to see, where to found this little square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Cck.jpg)